# What is the difference?

Tags: python, difference

There is a problem in Codeforces is talking about "equalizing the number of candies and oranges in n gifts. You can eat one candy or one orange or one candy and one orange from each gift in one move. You need to find the minimum number of moves required to equalize all the given gifts."
The correct solution of the problem is this

```
for _ in range(int(input())): 
    n = int(input())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))
    b = list(map(int, input().split()))
    mina = min(a)
    minb = min(b)
    nrm = 0
    for i in range(n):
        nrm = nrm + max(a[i] - mina, b[i] - minb)
    print(nrm)
```

I have made another solution and there it is

```
for _ in range(int(input())): 
    n = int(input())
    a = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    b = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    nrm = 0
    for i in range(n):
        nrm = nrm + max(a[i] - a[0], b[i] - b[0])
    print(nrm)
```

But the output of the two programs are different?

Input

```
5
3
3 5 6
3 2 3
5
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
3
1 1 1
2 2 2
6
1 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000
1 1 1 1 1 1
3
10 12 8
7 5 4
```

The output of the first solution

```
6
16
0
4999999995
7
```

The output of my solution

```
5
10
0
4999999995
6
```

Comment: @Matthias Can you explain more clearly please?

Comment: I don't even understand the result of the first solution. If we have (3, 5, 6) and (3, 2, 3) the resulting values should be 3 for the first sequence and 2 for the second sequence. So we have a difference of 1 (_(3-3)+(3-2)_)for the first value, 2 (_(5-3)+(2-2)_) for the second value and 4 (_(6-3)+(3-2)_) for the third value. This adds up to 7. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: @Matthias 
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1399/B

Comment: Ah, I see. Eating exactly one candy and exactly one orange together is only one move. Then I understand the usage of `max`. And that is exactly the problem with your solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't take into account that removing one candy and one orange together is only one move.

Here is a simple example how the second approach can go wrong. Imagine the following data: `[0, 0, 10]` for the candies and `[0, 10, 0]` for the oranges. The target value is now 0 candies and 0 oranges.

The first approach will give the following number of moves: `[0, 10, 10]`. Those add up to `20`.

In the second approach you sort the data first. Now you have `[0, 0, 10]` for the candies and `[0, 0, 10]` for the oranges. This will lead to the following number of moves: `[0, 0, 10]`. The total is `10`.